# Calling SOAP web service by Python WSDL library error

Tags: python, soap, wsdl

I have the following python program on Python 2.7 that uses python WDSL library.

```
>>> from SOAPpy import WSDL
>>> wsdlFile = 'my_wsdl_file_path'
>>> server = WSDL.Proxy(wsdlFile)
```

And I get below error;

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                                  
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>                                                                                                                                               
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/SOAPpy/WSDL.py", line 62, in __init__                                                                                                          
    self.wsdl = reader.loadFromStream(stream, wsdlsource)                                                                                                                           
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/SOAPpy/wstools/WSDLTools.py", line 34, in loadFromStream                                                                                       
    wsdl.load(document)                                                                                                                                                             
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/SOAPpy/wstools/WSDLTools.py", line 260, in load                                                                                                
    schema = reader.loadFromNode(WSDLToolsAdapter(self), item)                                                                                                                      
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/SOAPpy/wstools/XMLSchema.py", line 80, in loadFromNode                                                                                         
    schema.load(reader)                                                                                                                                                             
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/SOAPpy/wstools/XMLSchema.py", line 1088, in load                                                                                               
    self.addImportSchema(tp.getSchema())                                                                                                                                            
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/SOAPpy/wstools/XMLSchema.py", line 1205, in getSchema                                                                                          
    self._schema = reader.loadFromURL(url)                                                                                                                                          
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/SOAPpy/wstools/XMLSchema.py", line 114, in loadFromURL                                                                                         
    schema.load(reader)                                                                                                                                                             
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/SOAPpy/wstools/XMLSchema.py", line 1120, in load                                                                                               
    tp.fromDom(node)                                                                                                                                                                
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/SOAPpy/wstools/XMLSchema.py", line 1764, in fromDom                                                                                            
    self.setAttributes(node)                                                                                                                                                        
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/SOAPpy/wstools/XMLSchema.py", line 627, in setAttributes                                                                                       
    self.__checkAttributes()                                                                                                                                                        
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/SOAPpy/wstools/XMLSchema.py", line 681, in __checkAttributes                                                                                   
    %(self.getItemTrace(), a, self.attributes[a])                                                                                                                                   
SOAPpy.wstools.XMLSchema.SchemaError: <schema targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/DataSetGW4.xsd"><element name="DataSetGW4">, unknown attribute(urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata,{u'IsDataSet': u'true', u'UseCurrentLocale': u'true'})
```

what could be the reason?

Answer (score 1):

My experience with SOAPpy is that it is not as complete nor tolerant as [Suds](https://fedorahosted.org/suds/). Maybe you should try parsing your WSDL file with suds instead.

```
import suds.client as client
session = client.Client('file:///absolute/path/to/yourwsdl')
```